# How to add events in gcal on Linux?

Tags: linux, gcal

I tried adding events to gcal using gcal add event but it didn't work out. It doesn't give me an error but doesn't add anything either. Any help would be great. Thanks.

regards,
Pramit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the date and time where you want to create the event. Then a small popup menu appears showing you to Add or Edit the event. Click Add event and add the details and 'save' it. As simple as that !

Comment: The question was in-regards to command-line gcal, Anyways, I was able to figure it out, "gcal meeting with paul tomorrow at 7pm"